# Insert Multiple Textbox and Label value in single Query using For loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

```
for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
{
    conn.Open();
    string sQuery = "INSERT INTO TripSheet VALUES('" + lblDate1.Text + "','" + txtFuel1.Text+ "','" + txtRate1.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Here I am taking month `count` and I have to insert the Month of data using loop.

```
lblDate1.Text, txtFuel1.Text & txtRate.Text
```

This value I want to pass Like

```
lblDate[i].Text, txtFuel[i].Text & txtRate[i].Text    (Is it possible?)
```

Comment: What are the column names in `TripSheet `?

Comment: you can try with ToolStripTextBox

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlCommand is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block. And avoid constructing queries using string concatenation because it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would expect these values to be in some sort of a collection of objects where they have been scrubbed from the user interface.  For example as a List or and Array of a given type.  I would also typically see this inserting the SQL data by type of that data for example a `datetime` for the date, `VARCHAR(30)` for the name and so forth.  Now given I do not have visibility to that, I use the less desired perhaps `AddWithValue` here.  I typed this really fast so might be errors.  Put this in a proper set of classes and files.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Rates
{
    public class FuelRateThing
    {
        public DateTime RateDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public decimal FuelRate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string FuelName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public FuelRateThing()
        {
        }

        public FuelRateThing(DateTime date, decimal rate, string name)
        {
            RateDate = date;
            FuelRate = rate;
            FuelName = name;
        }
    }

    public class Ratethings
    {
        public void dostuff()
        {
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            //Create a class to manage these objects perhaps, here is a simple list example.
            // populate your list - normally parse and validation of UI values:
            List<FuelRateThing> monthRatesList = new List<FuelRateThing>()
            {new FuelRateThing{RateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20180101", "yyyyMMdd", provider), FuelRate = 3.45m, FuelName = "kerosene"}, new FuelRateThing{RateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20180102", "yyyyMMdd", provider), FuelRate = 3.49m, FuelName = "kerosene"}, new FuelRateThing{RateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20180103", "yyyyMMdd", provider), FuelRate = 3.48m, FuelName = "kerosene"}, new FuelRateThing{RateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20180104", "yyyyMMdd", provider), FuelRate = 3.65m, FuelName = "kerosene"}, new FuelRateThing{RateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20180105", "yyyyMMdd", provider), FuelRate = 3.60m, FuelName = "kerosene"}, };
            // add a couple more rows
            monthRatesList.Add(new FuelRateThing(DateTime.ParseExact("20180106", "yyyyMMdd", provider), 3.64m, "kerosene"));
            var newrate = new FuelRateThing{RateDate = DateTime.ParseExact("20180107", "yyyyMMdd", provider), FuelRate = 3.47m, FuelName = "kerosene"};
            monthRatesList.Add(newrate);
        }

        //Now use the data access code to insert those: (probably in a method that accepts a list of `FuelRateThings`:
        public class DataStore
        {
            public void SaveRateThings(List<FuelRateThing> rateList)
            {
                var _connectionSB = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                // do connections string stuff here
                var _connectionString = _connectionSB.ToString();
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    String query = @"
           INSERT INTO TripSheet (DateColumnName,FuelColumnName,RateColumnName)
           VALUES (@DateColumnName,@FuelColumnName,@RateColumnName)";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        foreach (FuelRateThing rate in rateList)
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateColumnName", rate.RateDate);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FuelColumnName", rate.FuelName);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RateColumnName", rate.FuelRate);
                            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To expand on Mark's "less desired AddWithValue", see [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: P.S. Mark, did you intend DataStore to be a nested class? Also, you would need to clear the parameters each time, if you're reusing the command in the loop like that.

Comment: @Richardissimo - nested is likely NOT the best here, but just pounded out a set of code that I could verify as easy as possible syntactically.   Yep, clear parameters etc.  just a super fast blast, will update later if I get a minute

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tab (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tab(a,b,c)
SELECT * FROM
(
  VALUES  
  (1,2,3),
  (10,20,30),
  (100,200,300)

) s(a,b,c);
```

c#

```
string temp="";
for (int i = 1; i <= daysCount; i++)
{
  if(i!=1)
   temp+=",";
  temp+="('" + lblDate1.Text + "','" + txtFuel1.Text+ "','" + txtRate1.Text + "')";
}
    conn.Open();
    string sQuery = "INSERT INTO TripSheet VALUES "+temp;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```